# Java - Check Response is JSON or not

Tags: java, json

I am  creating a Server HealthCheck page. Most of the servers return JSONObject and I am able to easily parse it using:

```
String jsonText = readAll(br);              
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
JSONObject resp = json.getJSONObject("Response");
```

Now my problem is the other servers that do not return JSON. Some are returning String, some pdf file some image and as all the responses are 200 OK I should return Positive healthcheck.

However I am using Future Threads and timing out my request after 4 secs. And all the servers which return anything other than JSON get stuck at " new JSONObject(jsonText);"

Is there any way I can check if the type of respone is JSON or not in Java?

Update:

I found my mistake - stupid one.
In the try catch block I am only catching IOException, which is not catching JSONException(and didnt show any error too - dunno y). I have added a new catch block for JSONException which works for my solution for now.

However, this isnt elegant solution, @Dave, @Radai and @Koi 's solutions is the right approach to go with.

Comment: Try to parse it as JSON. If it doesn't parse, it's not JSON. Check the response's content type. If it's a file check the extension. Etc.

Comment: why are they stuck? i'd expect some exception to be thrown .. are you reading the whole response into a string or runing the json parser right off the input stream ?

Comment: Dave I am already trying to parse it as JSON.

I am taking the response in a string "jsonText" and then putting this text in JSONObject. I get stuck at second step.

Comment: @radai I am 1. grabbing the response in string and 2. creating JSONObject with this jsonText

I am getting stuck at 2nd step. 

No exception is being thrown, except my thread timeout.

Comment: You should also check the Content-Type header of the response; JSON content should be sent as `application/json`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't parse the string. Go back one step, and check the `Content-Type` header of the HTTP response. If the response contains JSON data, the `Content-Type` should be `application/json` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)).

Comment: i don't believe this is a guarantee is it?

Comment: @woot4Moo its possible that JSOn response might have incorrect content-type but this is the official accepted format. Hence correct answer.
However you can check to make sure by putting try catch block - thats what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Check the MediaType in the response using **response.getMediaType()**. If it is json it returns application/json.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me;

```
  if (response.getMediaType().isCompatible(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)) {
      System.out.println("The media type matches application/json");
    } else {
      System.out.println("The media type does not match application/json");
    }
```